# Your app has been updated ... Restart meteor to use the new release

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I am trying to migrate to the latest version of meteor and after running `meteor update` it seems to go through ok but then when I run `meteor` to start the app, this is what happens:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
=> Started your app.   

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
Your app has been updated to Meteor 0.9.3.1 from Meteor METEOR@0.9.3.1.
Restart meteor to use the new release.
```

i.e. it just stops after seemingly starting successfully and says restart to use the new release...

P.S. the app is being updated from meteor 0.8.1.3

Comment: What does your `.meteor/release` file contain?

Comment: @DavidWeldon I can't believe that was it, since I assumed your question was leading I tried changing the release file contents to METEOR@0.9.3.1 and it worked! (it gave some other random errors after that like npm modules etc but those were at traceable). Feel free to post your suggestion as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had meteorite packages, I *think* the correct way to update is by using [mrt migrate-app](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/updating-to-090/). I had similar problems, but I just changed my `.meteor/release` file to `METEOR@0.9.3.1`, and then manually edited my `.meteor/packages`.

Comment: thanks Dave, this worked. `mrt migrate-app` was way more messy than `meteor update` actually so went with the latter option.